# Browsing for installed notes in SAP system

Tags: sap-basis

How can I view all installed SAP notes in a system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember correctly SPAU respective SPDD don't show up any SAP Note which was regularly installed by support packages (SPAM). Only SAP Notes are listed there, which were implemented by means of modification/correction and are in conflict.

Please run transaction SPAM to see which support package level you already have.

Comment: Though, it's not completely clear from your answer where to find full list of notes (both from SPs and modifications).

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish here? If you just want to see if a note is already applied, then I believe you can pull the note up in transaction SNOTE and check.

Comment: thank you! But Im not seeing notes which was exactly installed the day before

Answer (score 1):

Try transaction SPAU.  On the modifications Tab select "Corrections in SAP Note"